# How do i get the output of tkinter to print into GUI instead of CLI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have been working on with this code and I get my output to the terminal. How do i get the output to print in the tkinter GUI window insted? Here's the code:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
def ping():
    myinptext = entry.get()
    os.system("ping "+entry.get()+" -c 2" )
myGui = Tk()
entry = StringVar() 
myGui.geometry('300x300')
myGui.title("Get output inside GUI") 
mylabel = Label(myGui,text="Enter target IP or host as required.").pack() 
mybutton = Button(myGui,text ="Ping Test",command = ping).pack() 
myEntry = Entry(myGui,textvariable=entry).pack() 
myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: read about [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and how to get `stdout`

Comment: `Widget(...).pack()` returns `None` so you assign `None` to `mylabel`, `mybutton` and `myEntry`. If you really need variable `mylabel` you have to do in two steps `mylabel = Label(..)` and `mylabel.pack()`. But in your example you don't need this variables so you can do without variables - `Label(...).pack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead of [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). There are many functions to work with external command.

I use `subprocess.check_output()` to get result of executed command. Command has to be as list `["ping", entry.get(), "-c", "2"]`. Command can be single string if you use `shell=True`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess

def ping():
    cmd = ["ping", entry.get(), "-c", "2"]
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    #output = subprocess.check_output("ping {} -c 2".format(entry.get()), shell=True)

    print('>', output)
    # put result in label
    result['text'] = output.decode('utf-8')

my_gui = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.StringVar()

my_gui.geometry('300x300')
my_gui.title("Get output inside GUI") 

tk.Label(my_gui, text="Enter target IP or host as required.").pack() 
tk.Entry(my_gui, textvariable=entry).pack()
tk.Button(my_gui,text="Ping Test", command=ping).pack() 

# label for ping result
result = tk.Label(my_gui)
result.pack()

my_gui.mainloop()
```

BTW: because `ping` takes some time so `tkinter` will freeze for this time. If you need non-freezing version you will need other functions in `subprocess` or `threading` module.

Comment: thanks @furas that worked just fine. Much appreciated!